# Match ids in different layers by PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, features, filter

I have a CSV with a column of filtered ids, and because of the filter, the ids are out of order (they start at 23 and not 1) and from it I create another layer with the same number of features, but at the same time put the ids column in it, the ids start at 1, is there a possibility for me to match the ids of both layers? They have the same number of features

```
iface.addVectorLayer(url,'03p','delimitedtext')
camada = iface.activeLayer()
parameter = {
    'INPUT': camada,
    'TARGET_CRS': 'EPSG:31983',
    'OUTPUT': 'memory:Reprojected3'
}
layer = processing.run('native:reprojectlayer', parameter)['OUTPUT']
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
rp = layer.dataProvider()

filterstring = "\"Data/Hora GPS\" > '20/12/2019 12:33:00' AND \"Data/Hora GPS\" < '21/12/2019 16:51:00'" 
layer.setSubsetString(filterstring)


layer.startEditing()
fieldid = QgsField('id', QVariant.Double)
layer.addExpressionField("@id", fieldid)
layer.commitChanges()

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Reprojected3")[0] 

vl = QgsVectorLayer("linestring?crs=EPSG:31983","03","memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("Distancia(m)", QVariant.Double),
                 QgsField("Tempo(s)", QVariant.Double),
                 QgsField("Velocidade(cm/s)", QVariant.Double),
                 QgsField("Longitude", QVariant.Double)])

fieldid2 = QgsField('id', QVariant.Double)
vl.addExpressionField("@id",fieldid2)
```

Comment: Can you please share your data with us?